# CSS drop down menue using absolute positioning with a left:auto position

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

So I have your basic HTML menu structure:

```
<div id="page">

    <h1>Home</h1>
    <ul id="nav">
      <li><a href="http://example.com/">Home</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://example.com/">Nested Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://example.com/">Nested Item</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://example.com/">About Us</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://example.com/">Nested Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://example.com/">Nested Item</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://example.com/">Our Products</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://example.com/">Nested Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://example.com/">Nested Item</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://example.com/">Contact Us</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://example.com/">Nested Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://example.com/">Nested Item</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <h2>Stuff</h2>
    <p>
    Some text</p>
    <p>
    Some text.</p>

</div>
```

Here is the menu css:

```
#nav, #nav ul{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#nav a{
    display: block;
    border:1px solid cyan;
}

#nav li {
    border:1px solid;
    float: left;
}

#nav li ul {
/* note that this method hides the sub-items but they remain available to screen readers. this is important! you should never use display: none; as that removes the sub-items entirely. */
    position:absolute;
    width: 10em;
    left: -999em;
}

 #nav li:hover ul {
    left: auto;
}
```

My question is about the last CSS rule:

```
 #nav li:hover ul {
        left: auto;
    }
```

How does the "left:auto" bring the negative position of "left:-999em" back to normal and make a perfect drop down?

Out put [example](http://jsfiddle.net/5Jx4L/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original "left:-999em" is just 'hiding' the 'ul' by moving it so far off the page that it can't be seen. All the "left:auto" property is doing is resetting the 'ul' to its default position, where it can be seen.

See here:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_left.asp

It works because the "position:absolute" tag makes it so the 'ul' can appear on top of other content, and when you hover your mouse over the 'li' it sets the "left" value to its default.

See here
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Comment: @MilchePatern - w3fools itself is contradictory. W3Schools has been improving, however, w3fools didn't update its content on it. Also w3fools suggests wikifying W3Schools' content, but on the other hand w3fools didn't wikify its own content. It's time to accept W3Schools, in my and many SO users opinions...

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Thanks for this input. I realise you are somehow right about this and that maybe the bad reputation of w3school should be reconsidered.  From now on, i will stop repeating what 'many SO users suggested' and make my own opinion about this.